# Display products exactly bellow the categories they belong to

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to create a "php-mysql" system, where admin can create categories and products. products would be stored at the categories they belong dynamically and at the user interface those products would be displayed exactly bellow the categories they belong . For example: Right now my products are displayed like the following image: [image]

***I wanted them to be displayed like the following image :***

[image]

***My mysql tables are : 
for categories :***

[image]

***for products :***

[image]

***My codes(sql) so far are :***

```
function getCategory($category){
    $db_conn=getConnection();
    if(!$db_conn)return false;

    $sql="SELECT * from products where name='$category'";
    $result=$db_conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows>0){
        $db_conn->close();
        return false;
    }               
}


function getProduct(){
    $db_conn=getConnection();

    if(!$db_conn)return false;

    $sql="SELECT * from products";

    $result=$db_conn->query($sql);
    $db_conn->close();
    return $result;
}
```

php code :

```
<div class="category">
<?php $categories=getCategory(); ?>
<?php  while($category = $categories->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
<h2><?php echo $category['name'];?></h2>
```

```
<div class="products">
    <?php $products=getProduct(); ?>
    <?php  while($product = $products->fetch_assoc()):?>
<table>
   <tr><td><?php echo $category['name'];?></td></tr>
   <tr><td><?php echo $category['image'];?></td></tr>
   <tr><td><?php echo $category['price'];?></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Inside your categories listing, call getProduct($category) along category.

Comment: some advices (besides fixing SQL injections issue): in table products use the id of the category and not the description. Then JOIN the two tables in your select query by returning category JOIN product ON categories matching. Then it's just a matter of displaying

Answer (score 1):

Change your getProduct() function to the following so you get products based on category.

```php
function getProduct($category){
    // Fill the details appropriately or pass a db instance
    $db_conn = getConnection();

    // Check connection
    if ($db_conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $db_conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * from products WHERE category = ?";

    // Execute query
    $stmt = $db_conn->query($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $category);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
    $result = $result->fetch_assoc(); // fetch data   

    return $result;
}
```

In your HTML, do the following:

```html
<div class="category">
    <?php $categories=getCategory(); ?>
    <?php  while($category = $categories->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $category['name'];?></h2>

    <div class="products">
        <?php $products=getProduct($category['name']); ?>
        <?php  while($product = $products->fetch_assoc()):?>
    <table>
       <tr><td><?php echo $product['name'];?></td></tr>
       <tr><td><?php echo $product['image'];?></td></tr>
       <tr><td><?php echo $product['price'];?></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not check for connection errors manually. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Comment: I would also recommend to remove `$db_conn->close();`. You should not be closing it so early.

Comment: Sir,can you please tell me where should I declare $category variable and how . I am trying to get value using $_GET variable but it's not working , should I use $_GET variable or there are alternative methods of fetching data . Data should fetch like : SHOW DATA only Matches WITH THIS RAW NAME " . Thank you for your time .